# If condition not working with Titanic Kaggle dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kaggle

I'm using this Titanic dataset as `titanic_df` from Kaggle where I have created a new column `titanic_df['person']` and enter the values as child if passenger is below 16 or the sex of passenger if he/she is above 16. But the `if` condition is not being checked and `['person']` column gets the Sex of passenger as its values.

Here's what I did :

```
titanic_df= pd.read_csv('train.csv')

for age in titanic_df['Age']:

        if age < 16 :

          titanic_df['person']= 'child' 

        if age > 16 :

          titanic_df['person'] = titanic_df['Sex']

print titanic_df[:12]
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens because for every iteration of your loop, you are setting the *entire* `'person'` column to be equal whatever is relevant; it then happens that for the final iteration, the second clause is the one that comes into play.

You will probably want to use something like [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply). For example, in your case, you could do something like

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: 
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame()
   ...: df['Sex'] = ['Male', 'Female', 'Male']
   ...: df['Age'] = [15, 20, 50]
   ...: df
   ...: 
Out[1]: 
      Sex  Age
0    Male   15
1  Female   20
2    Male   50

In [2]: df['Person'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Child' if x['Age'] < 16 else x['Sex'], axis=1)

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
      Sex  Age  Person
0    Male   15   Child
1  Female   20  Female
2    Male   50    Male
```

In general, you very rarely end up needing to manually loop through your `Series`/`DataFrame`s.

Edit: Note also that for large DataFrames, the above code is greatly outperformed by @piRSquared's solution:

```
In [41]: n = 10**5

In [42]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [43]: df['Sex'] = np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], size=n)

In [44]: df['Age'] = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=n)

In [46]: df.head(10)
Out[46]: 
      Sex  Age
0  Female   15
1  Female   91
2  Female   50
3  Female   11
4  Female   59
5  Female   40
6  Female   50
7    Male   28
8    Male   13
9  Female   27

In [47]: %timeit np.where(df.Age.values < 16, 'Child', df.Sex.values)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.06 ms per loop

In [48]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: 'Child' if x['Age'] < 16 else x['Sex'], axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 5.73 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll echo what @fuglede said about assigning the entire column at every iteration through rows.  However, below is a vectorized approach at accomplishing your task using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Borrowing @fuglede's sample data

```
df['Person'] = np.where(df.Age.values < 16, 'Child', df.Sex.values)
print(df)

      Sex  Age  Person
0    Male   15   Child
1  Female   20  Female
2    Male   50    Male
```

Comment: That does indeed offer a huge performance boost already on semi-large datasets; I've added an example on that.